# Secure frontend connecting to backend with self signed certificates

Tags: security, ssl

Our frontend at domain.com uses an API located at api.domain.com.

For domain.com, we use SSL by LetsEncrypt. For the backend, however, it is much simpler to use self signed certificates.

Will users be presented with *Red Warning Banner* if they go to domain.com, which connects to https://api.domain.com with self signed certificates? Is this okay practice? Furthermore, can we replace https://api.domain.com with external IP instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a good idea in general. The purpose of a certificate is to allow a client to verify that it is actually talking to the right server, and not for example to a man-in-the-middle attacker. The way it does that (somewhat simplified) is the certificate includes the public key of the server, and the domain name ("common name") of the server the client intended to communicate with. The certificate is then signed by another certificate of about the same type and contents and so on, until the chain reaches a certificate that does not need to be signed by another, because it is already trusted by the client (it is in the trusted roots list of your OS for example).

A self-signed certificate doesn't have this chain of signatures, it is called self-signed, because the certificate used to sign it is itself. There is no way for a client to verify the certificate (unless it explicitly has it listed as trusted of course). This means an attacker can spoof (impersonate) your API by self-signing a different certificate for the same domain name, but with a different keypair. This might allow stealing credentials or serving fake data. Note that the attacker might also relay the information entered by the user (all the requests made) to the real API, so responses (also received by the attacker first, but relayed to the victim) can easily look very real without much background information.

This could (in theory) be solved by certificate pinning, but in case of a Javascript client that's going to be difficult (if at all possible). HPKP would seem like a solution, but HPKP won't work with a self-signed (not verifiable) certificate. I'm not sure if Javascript has an appropriate level of access to the server certificate to implement pinning.

Even if you did implement pinning, a self-signed certificate also cannot be revoked. Think about what would happen if you discovered a compromise of the TLS key used for https in your api domain. You would have no way to revoke the key, so clients would still accept a MitM attacker serving the compromised key.

There goes a lot of effort, and you could implement something that is not standard, hard to get right and error-prone.

Or you could just use a free letsencrypt certificate for api.domain.com as well, for which all the necessary infrastructure and setup is already done on the main domain. :)